# python openpyxl error

Tags: python, python3

openpyxlを用いてエクセルデータ(zipフォルダに入っていたので展開してｃｄに貼り付けたもの)を開こうとしたところ以下のエラーが発生しました。
解決方法をご教授ください。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 118, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1108, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1175, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    openpyxl.load_workbook("ファイル名")
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 171, in load_workbook
    archive = _validate_archive(filename)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 121, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(f, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1108, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1175, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

user名とファイル名は一応消しておきました。
大変失礼しました。コードを載せ忘れていました。
といっても2行ですが。

```
import openpyxl
openpyxl.load_workbook("ファイル名")
```

です。

コメントでご指摘いただいたのでzipフォルダに入っていたものをそのまま操作してみましたところ下記エラーが出ました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    openpyxl.load_workbook("ファイル名")
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", 
line 178, in load_workbook
wb_part = _find_workbook_part(package)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", 
line 138, in _find_workbook_part
    raise IOError("File contains no valid workbook part")
OSError: File contains no valid workbook part
```

[追記]関係ないかもしれませんが、拡張子のxlsをxlsxに変更していることを追記しておきます。

Comment: `File is not a zip file`のエラーが出ていますがこちらは確認済みですか？

Comment: コメントを頂いたのでその言葉について調べたのですがよくわかりませんでした。単純に　zipファイルではない　という意味だということは分かったのですが。

Comment: 残念ながら、openpyxl は `.xls` ファイル(Excel2003 format)をサポートしていませんので、xlrd ライブラリを使うか、元のファイルを `.xlsx` ファイル(Excel2007 format)に変換する必要があります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。拡張子を.xlsxに書き換えて保存しました。

Comment: @Hellopy3 さん、解決お疲れ様でした。スタック・オーバーフローでは、[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)ができ、また推奨されています。お手数ですが質問文中の解決方法を削除し、同じ内容を回答として投稿頂けませんでしょうか？　一定期間経つと自己回答を承認することもできるようになります。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。そのようにいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

・問題だった箇所
ファイル名から拡張子を`.xls`から`.xlsx`に書き換えました。

・解決に至った行動
一見変更できているように見えていましたが、一度エクセルファイルを開き名前を付けて保存するの画面で拡張子の確認をしたら、`.xlt`という見慣れぬ拡張子になっていました。
保存時に形式を選べるのでその画面で拡張子を変更することで解決しました。

力を貸してくださった方々ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

どのようなコードが使われてるのか判りませんが、問題は zipファイルではないファイルを、zipファイルを開く関数で開こうとした事にあります。

「zipフォルダに入っていたので展開してｃｄに貼り付けた」は、余分な（要らない）操作でした。
展開するまえのzipファイルを開けば、問題ないはずです。

Comment: 申し訳ありません解決しました。

Answer (score 0):

追加情報です。すでにご存知かもしれませんが、Officeのフォーマットはdocx/xlsxその他から、複数のXMLファイルで構成されています。(一度、ファイルの拡張しをzipに変えて、unzipすると、unzipできてしまうことにちょっと感動します。）普通にこれらを扱おうとすると、unzip→XMLパースとなるため、解析側は、unzipしよとしたけど、ZIPファイルじゃないよ！！というエラーになります。（不親切ですが。。）今回の事象はこのあたりに原因があるのかと思います。
また、このことを知っているだけで、UNZIPできない→ZIP前提→xlsx前提とわかるので metropolisさんのおっしゃっている内容に自力でたどり着くことが可能です。

Comment: 解説ありがとうございます。勉強になります。